# How to use google maps android SDK in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I am using android maps sdk and trying to plot a point on it. I followed the steps as given [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker)
I get an NPE saying that my Support Map Fragment is null. I am guessing this happens due to the fact that I am using view binding and setting the view as binding.getroot() in my main fragment.

The code where I declared this.

```
  SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);
  supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this::onMapReady);
```

The XML where I have declared this.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Had nothing to do with View binding.

Comment: can you just try  `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);` remove `getActivity()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `<fragment>` tag not `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`. `FragmentContainerView` is just a Container for fragments on which we can add fragments at runtime . on other hand `<fragment>` is itself a fragment this why the `android:name` attribute is there.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

If you using using it a fragment you should be using `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
  SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);
```

**Update**-> Yeah sorry i was wrong earlier . turns out  `FragmentContainerView` does support adding fragment in xml. Try the below code.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:tag="mapFragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then you can get the map fragment by using `#findFragmentByTag`.

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
```

Comment: Thanks this is working , however android studio still says replace fragment with fragmentcontainer

Comment: I have updated my answer . Hope i made it clear now . I wasn't sure before about `FragmentContainerView` capabilities.

Comment: Yeah it works even with Fragment Container View. The error was with the Fragment Manager thanks!